# MongoError: Authentication failed. Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

Estou rodando uma aplicação node e mongodb docker na minha maquina, porem quando tento conectar com o banco utilizando moogose retorna:

```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (D:\Node\08-multi-dbb-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:272:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at processIncomingData (D:\Node\08-multi-dbb-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (D:\Node\08-multi-dbb-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:435:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:419:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:309:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:728:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  name: 'MongoError'
}
```

Segue como estou fazendo a conexao:

file name: mongodb.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/dbname', 
    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function (error){
        if(!error) return;
        console.log('Falha na conexao!', error)
    }
)

const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open', () => console.log('database rodando!!'))
```

Eu consigo acessar o banco pelo client (interface visual) e consigo conectar com o banco tambem pelo terminal, dando um

```
docker exec -it 347b053d4320 mongo -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase myDb
```

Mas quando tento pelo codigo executando o arquivo mongodb.js, retorna o erro.

Se puderem me ajudar por gentileza.

Obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Se você manja de inglês, saca só o que eu achei:
[Conexão com docker container usando mongoose](https://medium.com/@anuradhs/connect-to-mongodb-docker-container-with-authentication-using-mongoose-and-nodejs-6319bea82e9d)

Pelo que eu entendi a autenticação usando docker funciona ligeiramente diferente do convencional.
Bom, mas não é só isso. Estou estudando mongo e ao que parece é necessário adicionar permissões ao banco de dados em questão. Tente o seguinte comando:

```
db.getUsers()
```

O primeiro banco a ser criado pelo mongo é o admin. Se você rodar o `getUsers()` vai ter uma saída como:

```
    > db.getUsers()
[
        {
                "_id" : "admin.henrique",
                "userId" : UUID("fa52408f-d9ed-43a2-b524-7b64233a2752"),
                "user" : "henrique",
                "db" : "admin",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ],
                "mechanisms" : [
                        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                ]
        },
        {
                "_id" : "admin.root",
                "userId" : UUID("2d668d76-4aa3-4ed2-b4a9-5836fdda1cc2"),
                "user" : "root",
                "db" : "admin",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "root",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ],
                "mechanisms" : [
                        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                ]
        }
]
```

Se você rodar no banco que você criou, provavelmente você tenha algo como:

```
[ ]
```

Ou seja, nenhum usuário tem permissões de manipular.

Bem provavel que nosso problema esteja nesse trecho da documentação:
[Adicionar usuário](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20user%20in,command%20to%20add%20the%20user.)

Irmãozão, vai aí uma maneira de solucionar sua dor.

Crie um novo usuário e dê permissão para editar o banco em questão. Funcionou para mim.

```
    db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUser",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(),  
    roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "meudb" }
    ]
  }
)
```

Como tudo no mongo é documento, o mongo cria um documento para dar controlar acesso também.
Detalhe extremamente importante. Mude para o db em questão.

```
use meubd;
```

Roles, são funções. Então nesse BSON de criação você coloca quais bancos esse usuário tem permissão e quais são essas permissões.

Minha API agora tá funcionando, espero que ajude.